# IE8 Throwing a Security Error with MooTools

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, mootools

Okay so like everything else IE8 is giving some serious problems. When trying to load MooTools into the browser IE8 just gives me a "A security problem occurred" error. I think it may have something to do with the clashing of files or something but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's a web address so you can see for yourself.

http://www.tylermorriswoodworking.com/pages/recipe-box-wizard?b=maple&l=cherry&c=42042892

Every other browser loads fine and what is weird is that the other pages load MooTools and my other javascript files just fine. What is happening!!

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: The link does not open for me

Comment: It opens for me, and I get the security exception too (in IE8).

Comment: Does it still happen if you use a self-hosted copy of Mootools?

Comment: Yep. I've tried different servers and changing permissions. It still happens. But like try the homepage, everything will load just fine.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in IE with the given URL. Can you elaborate further on the error? Have you tried using the developer tools to get further detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try to get some information out of the debugger in IE8, it seems that it chokes trying to set the `src` property of some element to this value:

```
http://tmorris28:xxxxxx@antiradiant.com/clients/TMW/rbwizard/images/cherrylarge.jpg
```

(removed the password in case it is sensitive info - it's somewhere in the source though)

**Update:** I think I know what this is. This way of passing auth info was disabled in IE8 for security purposes. I thought that was the case for Firefox too, but it works there.

Answer (score 1):

Something's trying to set a property on an element such that IE gets upset. It's pretty hard to tell what *exactly* the issue is. If it were me, I'd make a temporary change to that MooTools function where IE is reporting the error. I'd just put a try/catch around that line and then do an "alert" or something (doesn't IE8 have a "console" that you can log stuff to, like Firebug?) to print out what kind of element it is, and what the "key" is.  Then you can probably track down the code that's trying to *use* MooTools in the offending way.

*edit* — wait I can see more detail now. Something's trying to set the "src" attribute on some page element. The URL is

> http://tmorris28:XXX@antiradiant.com/clients/TMW/rbwizard/images/cherrylarge.jpg

(The "XXX" is actually a password on the page.) I suspect that IE is not liking the idea of an embedded URL that includes a username/password like that, but that's just a guess.

Comment: ooooh ya let me take a look at that.

Comment: @Tyler the `username:password` scheme was disabled in IE8. @Pointy, we found the same thing at the same time :) +1.